# Set a source of MultiScaleImage control in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am setting the source of an MultiScaleImage control but its not showing up me the imgae.:(

Below is the code ..

```
   <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" >
        <MultiScaleImage Width="100"  Height="100" Source="Image/Chrysanthemum.jpeg" />
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

The multiscaleimage control is expecting to receive a url to xml content created by the Deep Zoom image composer.  Its this xml file which contains the references to the tile images that make up a multi-scale image.

Comment: so what will be the source set to ?

Comment: +1 You need to set the source as an xml. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd901589(v=VS.95).aspx